# Does std::wcout change the encoding of the characters according to the current associated std::locale object before sending data to the console?

Tags: c++, unicode, stdout, iostream, ostream

If so, what is the target encoding for the default "C"-locale?

I have tried to answer the question with a short testcode but the results are inconsistent:

```
BOOL success = SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);

// characters are saved using UTF-16 here (OS: windows)
wchar_t char_a    = L'a';     // exists in ascii 
wchar_t umlaut    = L'ö';     // exists in local codepage (1252)
wchar_t euroSign  = L'€';     // exists in local codepage (1252)
wchar_t omega     = L'Ω';     // unicode bmp
wchar_t pileOfPoo[] = L"";  // unicode, surrogate, beyond bmp 


//std::locale loc("German_Germany.1252"); 
//std::wcout.imbue(loc);

// conversion from UTF-16 to target encoding specified in locale
std::wcout << char_a << std::endl;      
std::wcout << umlaut << std::endl;      
std::wcout << euroSign << std::endl;
std::wcout << omega << std::endl;
std::wcout << pileOfPoo << std::endl;


// --- Results ---


// Test 1: Default 'c'-locale:
// a -> works
// ö -> works
// euroSign -> does not work
// omega -> does not work (expected)
// pileOfPoo -> does not work (expected)


// Test 2: Locale: German_Germany.1252
// a -> works
// ö -> works
// euroSign -> works
// omega -> does not work (expected) (but outputs "0" why?)
// pileOfPoo -> does not work (expected)
```

I have changed the console output to codepage 1252 (local codepage) for easier readability. 
It seems that the characters which are encoded in UTF-16 here ARE converted dependending on the std::locale. But I do not understand 
why the umlaut works and the euro sign does not. If the "c"-local uses ASCII-encoding as target encoding no non-ASCII character should work, cause there is no 
corresponding character. But the umlaut works, so I have assumed that the default conversion is the local codepage (1252). My local codepage contains the umlaut and the euro sign,
but only the umlaut character works.

Is it true that std::cout (narrow-version) does not convert the characters so it is save to output wide-strings converted to UTF-8 with the only drawback that windows console may be not able 
to display all characters.

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing the console font. The default probably does not support the euro.

Comment: Test 2 (Using Local German_Germany.1252) shows the euro sign in the console and the console has the same font in both tests.

Comment: `L''` compiles? U+1f49c PILE OF POO cannot be represented as a single UTF-16 code unit which is what `wchar_t` can hold in Windows. I suspect that if it is compiling you are getting a multi-character literal (which is an obscure feature of C++) which is an `int` and then it gets converted to a wchar_t with an integral conversion (is it even defined?)

Comment: The code compiles but you are right, it is not correct to save this codepoint into a single codeunit. I have overlooked the compiler  warning. Hoever this bug does not affect the question.